# eBay API HTTP request works through cURL but does not work through javascript

Tags: javascript, api, http, curl

So, I'm trying to use the eBay API's. I should mention that from the beginning I've had issues with cross origin requests, but I got a CORS chrome add on that is supposed to disable it, and works fine for the initial request to get a user auth token. I don't know backend programming at all, but I've heard you can use a proxy to deal with the CORS issue. I tried downloading a few different proxy scripts but none of them seemed to send the headers correctly.

When I make a request using cURL everything works fine. But when I try to make that same request in javascript using xmlhttprequest it keeps telling me it's missing authorization headers, when I've clearly set them. Anyone know why it might be saying authorization headers are missing?

Here's the xmlhttprequest I'm trying to use:

```
var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr2.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr2.responseText);
    }
}
xhr2.open('PUT', 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/testingItemSKU1234');
xhr2.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <token>');
xhr2.setRequestHeader('Content-Language', 'en-US');
xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var reqBody2 = "request body info";
xhr2.send(reqBody2);
```

EDIT:

Here is the response

```
    {
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorId" : 1002,
    "domain" : "OAuth",
    "category" : "REQUEST",
    "message" : "Missing access token",
    "longMessage" : "Access token is missing in the Authorization HTTP request header."
  } ]
}
```

And here is the cURL command that works:

```
curl.exe -X PUT "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/testitemSKU1234"
-H "Content-Language: en-US" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -d "request body"
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message here?

Comment: Also please paste the curl request that works.

Comment: Okay, I added them.

Comment: What do you mean _"I tried downloading a few different proxy scripts"_? You can write your own proxy, make a request to an endpoint on your server, and make a [crul](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request via php, and return it to the client

Comment: I don't know php at all, so don't know how to write a script like that. A few people have posted scripts to do that, that's what I used and they worked except for the headers didn't get sent through properly.

Comment: @jBob Your question is tagged under the `php` tag, please [edit] it and only include the relevant tags

Comment: Using `curl -i` will show the request headers as well. Compare them with the headers your browser sends (network debug view in your browser). Are they the same?

Comment: @Shi when I use -i it's only showing me the response headers. On the request that isn't working it's having the error at the OPTIONS preflight request, and the only thing it shows in regards to an authorization header is the header "Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,content-type"

Comment: I'm thinking this is a CORS issue. Maybe I'll start learning PHP so I know how to write my own proxy. One thing I don't understand is why doesn't the eBay API documentation mention anything about this cross domain issue? I've asked in their forums and no one replied, but it seems like an issue everyone would run into.

Comment: I think eBay API document does not mention this because: normally, API invocation with access token won't be triggered directly from browser, it's insecure and will leak your token.

Comment: Then what is the typical solution, creating a proxy?